# Basic math interpreter

Tags: python, python-2.x, interpreter

Essentially what I've done here is written an Interpreter that takes in Python math, such as this, `23 ** 374748`, and prints out the result. This program relies on the fact that in Python 2.7 `input()` is "broken". This means it can take in Python math.

```
# Main parser class
class Parser(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.PROMPT = "MaTh @ ==> "
        self.ERR_MSG = "Error: Invalid math!"

    # Parse inputted math
    def parse_math(self):
        while True:
            try:
                math = input(self.PROMPT)
                print "{}\n".format(math)
            except:
                print self.ERR_MSG


# Run the program
if __name__ == "__main__":
    Parser().parse_math()
```

Can I improve anything here? Is it possible for this to be Python3 compatible?

Comment: You can approximate the behaviour of Python 2 `input()` by using `eval(input())` in Python 3.

Comment: From [this](http://pyvideo.org/video/880/stop-writing-classes) PyCon video: "if it has two methods, one of which is `__init__`, it shouldn't be a class." You could write a single standalone `parse_math` function that did exactly the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For 2.x and 3.x compatibility, I would explicitly use `eval(raw_input(...))`; you can then use:

```
import sys

if sys.version_info[0] > 2:
    raw_input = input
```

This makes more sense if you're writing for 2.x first, and is slightly easier than shoehorning `eval` onto 3.x's `input` everywhere you need it (which also makes life more difficult everywhere you don't).

Also for compatibility, `print` is a function in 3.x. You can import from `__future__`, or just use

```
print("{}\n".format(math))
```

in both.

---

You could make the constants *class attributes*:

```
class Parser(object):

    PROMPT = "..."
    ERR_MSG = "..."

    def parse_math(self):
        ...
```

These are still accessible via `self`, so your other code doesn't change. Note that now there are no instance attributes, you don't need `__init__`. In fact, you could take this further and make `parse_math` a *class method*, then you don't need to create an instance to call it.

---

Try giving the user a way to escape the loop. Perhaps:

```
while True:
    math = raw_input(self.PROMPT)
    if math.lower() == "done":
        break
    try:
        math = eval(math)
    except (NameError, SyntaxError):
        print(self.ERR_MSG)
    else:
        print("{}\n".format(math))
```

Note here also

- Splitting input and evaluation to allow pre-evaluation checking;
- Catching *specific* errors (see e.g. [here](http://blog.codekills.net/2011/09/29/the-evils-of--except--/)); and
- Using the `else` to minimise the code in the `try` block.

---

Finally, your code has no documentation. This is simple enough to not really need it, but it's a habit worth getting into. See e.g. [PEP-257](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/).

Answer (score 3):

### Security

This program is capable of doing **a lot more** than just interpreting math.  Consider what will happen with…

```
MaTh @ ==> list(open('/etc/passwd'))

MaTh @ ==> __import__('os').unlink(__import__('sys').argv[0])
```

In summary, any kind of `eval()` is dangerous, and you should be *extremely* cautious about feeding arbitrary user input to be evaluated (which is what `input()` does).

### Misnomer

Your `MathParser` is much more than a parser — it's a full read-eval-print loop.

### Infinite loop

There is no clean way to exit the program, not even <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>EOF</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

#### How to get out?

It would be good to have an intuitive way to exit the interpreter. With `Control-D` for example. It triggers an `EOFError`, so you could do that like this:

```
try:
    math = input(self.PROMPT)
    print("{}\n".format(math))
except EOFError:
    print('')
    break
except:
    print(self.ERR_MSG)
```

Before breaking out of the loop, I added a `print('')` to print a blank line, otherwise the shell will return control to the user in the middle of the prompt line. This way you could do things like:

```
python math_interpreter.py <<< '3 + 4'
# or
echo '3 + 4' | python math_interpreter.py
```

To work in both Python 2.7+ and 3.0, I changed the `print something` statements to Python 3 style `print(something)`.

#### Use class attributes

Instead of setting `PROMPT` and `ERR_MSG` in `__init__`, you could make them class attributes:

```
class Parser(object):
    PROMPT = "MaTh @ ==> "
    ERR_MSG = "Error: Invalid math!\n"
```

#### Python 3 support

As [@Greg](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/9717/greg-hewgill) said, you can use `eval(input())` in Python 3 to approximate the behavior of `input()` in Python 2. To make the program work with both Python versions, you need to detect the version and switch the implementations accordingly. Maybe with something like this:

```
import sys
if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
    def input_and_eval(prompt):
        return input(prompt)
else:
    def input_and_eval(prompt):
        return eval(input(prompt))
```

You can use this `input_and_eval` function, which wraps the version specific prompting and evaluation.

#### Suggested implementation

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
    def input_and_eval(prompt):
        return input(prompt)
else:
    def input_and_eval(prompt):
        return eval(input(prompt))


class Parser(object):
    PROMPT = "MaTh @ ==> "
    ERR_MSG = "Error: Invalid math!\n"

    def parse_math(self):
        while True:
            try:
                math = input_and_eval(self.PROMPT)
                print("{}\n".format(math))
            except EOFError:
                print('')
                break
            except:
                print(self.ERR_MSG)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Parser().parse_math()
```